# Sql Query into excel

Tags: sql, excel-2007

I have a sql query that pulls in form multiple tables, how can I run that query to import into an excel sheet?

Comment: Copy and paste the query results into excel.

Comment: if you're still using SQLServer, Kevin's answer is the simplest. (from the results grid in SQLServer Management Studio.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that's 'from multiple tables'. In Excel got to the Data menu > Get External Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Query and open an ODBC connect. If you can't get the query right in Microsoft Query declare it as a View in your Database and of course you need an ODBC connection to the database

Answer (score 0):

Not knowning your toolset, or even DB Platform, here's a guess.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1202